# Why are my authorize transactions being settled before full payment has been captured?

Tags: magento-1.9, authorize.net

I am using Authorize (not Direct Post) to capture payments as invoices are created. The problem is that many orders are becoming settled before the order is complete.

My default order status is "Order Attempted" with a state code of processing[processing].

Upon Authorization at checkout...

- The order status is changed to Payment Authorized.
- A cron job then looks at orders with these status, pulls them into our order fulfillment center and changes the status to Processing.
- As parts of the order are fulfilled they're returned and invoiced.
- For every invoice we attempt to capture the portion of the payment due.
- If the order is still incomplete the order import module changes the order status to Partially Shipped (state code of processing[processing]).
- Once all items are invoiced magento default functionality takes over and sets the order status to complete.

## The issue:

After the first invoice, on some orders, the authorize transaction becomes settled. This is no good because, of course, we cannot capture the rest of the due payment unless we go into authorize and create a re-bill.

If it helps, I noticed that in the comment history that when a payment is captured the order status reverts to the processing default of Order Attempted **and then** is changed to Partially Shipped.

Comment: Hi, did you find any solution to this problem. Please share it. thanks

Comment: We've since implemented Braintree, which behaves the same. We extended Braintree so that when capturing an invoice, if it is already expired we create a new transaction. We have to force vault payments to accomplish this.

Comment: Thanks for sharing :)  We are still busy in solving this issue, It looks really a difficult one to solve, as your question is  still unanswered.